# How to display value in xslt variable

Tags: xslt

how can I store element with attributes into xslt variable and then display element through this variable ?

Example:

```
<element name="value1" attribute2="value2" />
```

I tried something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVariable" select="../element[@name=value1]" />
```

and then display:

```
<xsl:template match="..">
    <xsl:value-of select="$myVariable" />
</xsl:template>
```

And I want to display element with given name with all attributes.

Thanks

Krp0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been missing the qoutes around `value1`. To access the value of the variable use `xsl:copy-of` which copies an element with all attributes.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="myVariable" select="element[@name='value1']" />
  <xsl:copy-of select="$myVariable" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

`value-of` creates a text node with the string value of the selected value, if you want to copy a node to the output use `copy-of`, e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="$myVariable"/>`.